# SpirePDF :- High Resoultion the images gets pixelated or cut?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, spire

We have used SpirePdf in Wpf application. In low resolution the images in the table works fine but when the same image is opened in High resolutions images it gets torn or disturbed.

[High resolution images torn 144 DPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Azm.jpg)

[Low resolution image 92 DPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yb7g.jpg)

I have tried to save the byte to pdf and file is generated perfectly but in spire pdf when SaveAsImage is called it disturbs the images in high resolution

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();

pdf.UseHighQualityImage = true;
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

As we have used Spire PDF 3.6 version the issue was resolved in 3.8. So this problem has been resolved. Try to check the updated version of spire pdf or version in your license period